# Bigquery Row-level security

Tags: google-bigquery, row-level-security

Maybe someone has a chance to work with Big query row-level security?

I faced with this issue CREATE ROW ACCESS POLICY is not supported

but I try to use code snippet from off doc

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-row-level-security#syntax

Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE ROW ACCESS POLICY Quote_Store_ID_filter
ON `my_dataset.my_table`
GRANT TO ("user:**.**@**.**.**")
FILTER USING (True);
```

return
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i95JX.png)

PS: I have permissions:
BigQuery Admin
BigQuery Data Owner

Answer (score 0):

For now, I see only one reason. Project allocation I have three projects, two in Europe one in the USA. In all of these projects, I'm an owner. In us-central-1 all good but in europe-west-2(London) and europe-east-*(Warshaw) it doesn't work.

Comment: This is puzzling... It should not be happening since row-level security is Generally available since a few days ago.. (https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/bigquery-provides-tighter-controls-over-data-access).. maybe a temporary bug that they'll fix soon ?

Comment: I hope.
I opened an Issue in their bug tracker
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191817364
But they don't hurry up to fix this issue

Comment: @Cylldby - I am hiring. PM me if interested :o)